# What is the name of the new bottom menu in Lollipop

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-5.0-lollipop

I'd like to use the new bottom menu of lollipop, but I don't know the name of the View. Does anyone know its name? This menu can be used to shows video?

This menu shows on long click on the home.

[image]

Comment: I think Bottom sheets. Look at this : http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. Can I add a mediaplayer?

Comment: Check this one https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Answer (score 1):

Bottom menu? It's a simple Share Intent view that the OS pop out.
You can get it via:

```
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test text");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test subject"));
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
context.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Or instead of starting the activity like this, you can do the following:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share is via..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the menu created by the [Intent#createChooser(Intent, CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method. And I doubt you can show video via it.